# Is this the main cause for application crash while launching Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication delegate]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a doubt that when my application launches there is crash and showing that while putting a exception breakpoint i have got this

Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication delegate]

can anyone answer if this cause application crash or not

Comment: It can cause crashes and slow and erratic performance of your app.

Comment: "can anyone answer if this cause application crash or not" No, but it is diagnostic of a threading error that could crash the app.

Comment: i have found a solution that checking if the UI API is not in main thread it makes to the main thread otherwise normal execution